# Global ressources not reachable through Resources class

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, resources, app-globalresources

I've created a Silverlight Business Application and want to use App_GlobalResources.

The resources are in the same project (TestApp.Web). Trying to use some resources through System.Resources. in a class doesn't work, because there is no class listed.

I see only RegistrationDataResources and ValidationErrorResources.

Maybe you have an idea?

Edit:
Using Resources.te23. brings up an error. "Type or Namspace te23 is not available in TestApp.Web.Resources" (translated to English)

Content of "te23" ressource (I removed the comments).

```
namespace Resources {
using System;
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.StronglyTypedResourceProxyBuilder", "10.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
internal class te23 {
    private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan; 
    private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    internal te23() {
    }
   [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.te23", global::System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
        get {
            return resourceCulture;
        }
        set {
            resourceCulture = value;
        }
    }
    internal static string test {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("test", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited the namespaces from Resources to TestApp.Web.Resources. Now they are listet under Resources.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, do you have the library reference to the specific library?

Comment: The resources are within the same project. (updated my post above)

Comment: I was referring to your references folder in your project, i was once in the same situation. I had not put any reference to the System.Resources DLL .

Comment: Actually, there is no reference to System.Resources.dll. But I can't find this reference in the Add Reference window:-/

Comment: And also right click on the resource file and view the properties then change the "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource" so it will become available

Comment: The property "Build Action" was set to "Content". After setting it to "Embedded Resource" I cleaned up and rebuild the project. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally a build issue.  Verify that the *Custom Tool* property of the .resx file is set to "GlobalResourceProxyGenerator".

(Note that you'd access resources using *Resources.MyResxFile.ResourceName*.)

Comment: the property is already set to "GlobalResourceProxyGenerator".

Comment: @float wait, you created the resources in the web project, right?  Are you trying to access them from that project, or from the Silverlight project?

Comment: I'm trying to access them from the web project, not from the Silverlight project.

Comment: @float hm, strange, seems like it should work.  Let me ask you this: What do you see in the Resource.designer.cs file?  Is the namespace *Resources*?  Is the class *public* or *internal*?  Another thing to try might be to use *PublicResXFileCodeGenerator* as the custom tool.

Comment: I've updated my Post. There you can see the designer.cs file of my test resource and the error message if I try to use it.

Comment: @float did you try using *PublicResXFileCodeGenerator*?  That's really my only other idea; it should make *te23* *public* rather than *internal* (although I'm not sure if that would help).

Comment: There is a Resources Folder unter TestApp.Web. Looks like the Folder App_GlobalResources gets ignored. If I type Resources, I get a list of resources unter TestApp.Web.Resources. Designer.cs files in this folder have the namespace TestApp.Web.Resources.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13474/discussion-between-dbaseman-and-float)